Migrating Legacy App to Web with Direct Document Links on Box.com
I have been tasked with developing a web application to replace a legacy desktop application that has been in use for 20 years. I am encountering challenges in replicating a specific functionality from the old application.
The previous application allowed direct linking to document files stored on a mapped drive, connected to an on-premise file server. In the new web application, we are transitioning from the local file server to Box.com, but the client insists on maintaining the capability of direct links to documents from the web application.
Unfortunately, I have not been successful in finding suitable solutions to implement this feature.
I am seeking advice and potential approaches from the community to address this challenge. Specifically, I would appreciate insights on:

Best practices for integrating Box.com to provide seamless direct document linking from a web application.
Alternative solutions or technologies that may offer more stable integration.
Strategies to overcome common pitfalls encountered when transitioning from on-premise file servers to cloud-based storage solutions in web applications.

Any guidance or recommendations on how to successfully implement this functionality would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
I did experiment with using a combination of OneDrive, SharePoint, and Word Online in an attempt to overcome this challenge, but I encountered unpredictable issues with SharePoint, which hindered the stability of the solution.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
